# Exception 7 bad data address error in mips function

Tags: assembly, mips

the mips assembly program below is the function qselect which is part of the quickselect algorithm. When compilling, it prints  "Exception 7  [Bad data address]  occurred and ignored\n"
I haven't yet understood exactly what that means or how I can fix it. Perhaps the partition function has the issue

```
qselect:
    # a0 = f
    # a1 = l
    # a2 = k

    addi $sp, $sp, -4 #adjust stack for 1 item
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

 if1:
    #if !(f < 1+l) goto else0
    addi $t0, $a1, 1 #t0 = l+1
    slt $t0, $a0, $t0 #if f<1+l t0 = 1
    beq $t0, $zero, else0 # if t0 = 0 goto else0
#int p = partition(f,l);
    jal partition #v0 becomes p
    lw $ra, 0($sp) #restore ra
    #if (p==k) goto else_if2 
    beq $v0, $a2,else_if2
    
 if2:  #if p < k return qselect(f,p-1,k);
    slt $t1, $a2, $v0 #if p > k, t1 = 1
    beq $t1, $zero, qselectp1lk # if t1 = 0 goto qselectp1lk

qselectfp1k:
    #return qselect(f,p-1,k);
    addi $a1, $v0, -1 # a1 = p-1
    jal qselect
    lw $ra, 0($sp) # restore ra
    j end_qselect

    else0: #return v[f];
    la $t0, v # t0 = address of v
    sll $t1, $a0, 2 # t1 = 4*f
    add $t1, $t1, $t0 #t1 = address of v[f]
    lw $v0, 0($t1) #v0 = v[f]
    j end_qselect
 
    else_if2:
    #return v[k];
    la $t0, v # t0 = address of v
    sll $t1, $a2, 2 # t1 = 4*k
    add $t1, $t1, $t0 #t1 = address of v[k]
    lw $v0, 0($t1) #v0 = v[k]
    j end_qselect

    qselectp1lk: # return qselect(p+1,l,k);
    addi $a0, $v0, 1 # a0 = p+1
    jal qselect
    lw $ra, 0($sp) #restore ra

    end_qselect:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 #restore stack
    jr $ra #return to caller
```

Comment: `$a0`..`$a2` are caller saved, so depending on their values across a `jal` is bad. Apart from that, use your simulator to single step the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: You get that error when *assembling*, before running?  If that's actually true, sounds like a bug in whichever assembler you're using.

Comment: This needs to be debugged.  Use the debugger to find out what instruction is failing, and what memory address is causing its failure.  Then use the debugger to find out who made the bad memory address.  We are not a debugging service, and will struggle to help you given incomplete code.  Your register usages are non-standard, but that can work if all the callees follow the same non-standard approach.